# Why does the println! function use an exclamation mark in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Swift, `!` means to unwrap an optional (possible value).

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[`println!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.println.html) is not a function, it is a *macro*. Macros use `!` to distinguish them from normal method calls. [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) contains more information.

See also:

- [What is the difference between macros and functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29871967/155423)

---

Rust uses the [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) type to denote optional data. It has an [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) method.

Rust 1.13 added the question mark operator `?` as an analog of the `try!` macro (originally proposed via [RFC 243](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md)).

An excellent explanation of the question mark operator is in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator).

```
fn foo() -> Result<i32, Error> {
    Ok(4)
}

fn bar() -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let a = foo()?;
    Ok(a + 4)
}
```

The question mark operator also [extends to `Option`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md#generalize-over-result-option-and-other-result-carrying-types), so you may see it used to unwrap a value or return `None` from the function. This is different from just unwrapping as the program will not panic:

```
fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    None
}

fn bar() -> Option<i32> {
    let a = foo()?;
    Some(a + 4)
}
```

Answer (score 31):

`println!` is a macro in rust, that means that rust will rewrite the code for you at compile time.

For example this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Will be converted to something like this at compile time:

```rust
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    {
        ::std::io::_print(::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
            &["", "\n"],
            &match (&x,) {
                (arg0,) => [::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(
                    arg0,
                    ::core::fmt::Display::fmt,
                )],
            },
        ));
    };
}
```

*Notice that the `&x` is passed as a reference.

It's a macro because it does things that functions can't do:

- It parses the format string at compile time, and generates type safe code
- It has a variable number of arguments
- It has named arguments ("keyword arguments")

  ```
  println!("My name is {first} {last}", first = "John", last = "Smith");
  ```

sources:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print.html.
- https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4qor4o/newb_question_why_is_println_a_macro/
- [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable)