# Why is the size of a pointer to something on the heap larger than the size of a stack variable?

Tags: pointers, reference, rust, smart-pointers, memory-layout

I have the following stack- and heap-allocated variables:

```
let var1 = 10;
let var2 = Box::new(10);
```

Printing these outputs the same value, `10`:

```
println!("var1 ={} var2 ={}", var1, * var2);
```

When I check the size using `mem::size_of_val()`, `var1` is 4 and `var2` is 8.

Isn't `var2` a pointer to the heap? Why would a pointer be larger than the stack variable (`var1`)?

Also, is the use of "`*`" (i.e., `*var2`) in the `println!()` supposed to do anything different? I get 10 either way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't show your code for how you are invoking `mem::size_of_val` but I guess from the results that you are doing this:

```
println!("var1 size = {}", mem::size_of_val(&var1)); // 4
println!("var2 size = {}", mem::size_of_val(&var2)); // 8
```

The size of `var1` is the size of an `i32` (4 bytes), while the size of `var2` is the size of a `Box`, which is just a pointer (it would be two pointers if it was a trait object). A pointer is always a `usize` (8 bytes on a 64bit system).

If you dereference the box first, then the size will be that of the box's contents and you'll get the result you expect:

```
println!("var2 size = {}", mem::size_of_val(&*var2)); // 4
```

> Also, is the use of "`*`" (i.e., `*var2`) in the `println!()` supposed to do anything different? I get 10 either way.

The `println!` macro, along with `format!` and a few others, will always prepend a `&` to a value to make sure that it's borrowed, not moved or copied. When the value is needed it will be automatically dereferenced as many times as is necessary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30451360/493729) for more detail.