# Why use a reference to an immutable vector in a for loop?

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

In [Chapter 8 of the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-01-vectors.html) they give they following [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-01-vectors.html#iterating-over-the-values-in-a-vector):

```
let v = vec![100, 32, 57];
for i in &v {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

I don't understand why `&v` was used instead of `v`.

If `v` is immutable what is the purpose of using a reference instead of `v` itself?

Comment: I'm not a rust developer but I'm guessing that without the reference notation (`&`) the program will try to copy `v`?

Comment: No, Rust will not automatically copy most types, including a `Vec`. The value would be moved and no longer available.

Comment: @Shepmaster I didn't realize a for loop would take ownership like that. I (incorrectly) assumed it would behave like `if s == "str"` or `println!("{}", s)` which do not appear to take ownership.

Comment: Certainly. However, [`PartialEq` takes `&self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq) and [`println!` is a macro and takes its arguments by reference for usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable).