# How do I get groups for a user via libc::getgroups?

Tags: rust, libc

```
extern crate libc;

fn example(guid: u32) {
    unsafe {
        let ruid = libc::getuid();
        libc::seteuid(guid);
        let mut v = vec![0; 0];
        let num_groups = libc::getgroups(0, v.as_mut_ptr());
        let mut groups = Vec::with_capacity(num_groups as usize);
        libc::getgroups(num_groups, groups.as_mut_ptr());
        println!(
            "real user id {} as user id {}, as user groups {:?}, numgroups {}",
            &ruid, &guid, &groups, &num_groups
        );
    }
}
```

This prints

```
real user id 1000 as user id 1000, as user groups [], numgroups 9
```

My assumptions was that it would show a vector of 9 groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the size of `groups` by adding dummy elements, not just its capacity.  Something like this:

```
unsafe {
    let ruid = libc::getuid();
    let guid = libc::getgid();
    let num_groups = libc::getgroups(0, ::std::ptr::null_mut());
    let mut groups = vec![0; num_groups as usize];
    libc::getgroups(num_groups, groups.as_mut_ptr());
    println!(
        "real user id {} as user id {}, as user groups {:?}, numgroups {}",
        &ruid, &guid, &groups, &num_groups
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Can you explain why `with_capacity` doesn't work even if I `push` element after that?

Comment: @user1685095 A C function wouldn't care about the capacity or size of the vector and won't change them. So as far as the vector is concerned, it is still empty after your call to `getgroups`.

Comment: It is also my understanding that you can just pass a null pointer to your first call to `getgroups`.

Comment: @user1685095 Where do you push the elements? Not in the code you posted.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I saw your initial answer and tried `with_capacity`

Answer (score 2):

- None of your code checks for errors! `seteuid` and `getgroups` can **fail** but your code ignores that possibility. You are attempting to debug a failure but haven't even spent the time to check that the functions you are calling are succeeding.
- Be very careful about passing in `v.as_mut_ptr()`. An empty `Vec` does **not** have a NULL pointer. In this case it's fine because the man page says it only cares about the count.
- You don't handle the case where the number of groups changes in size between the first and second call.
- [You don't need to pass in references to the `println` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423).

With that out of the way, since you are only storing `u32` in the `Vec`, you can avoid filling it with dummy values by adjusting the size and capacity accordingly:

```
extern crate libc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Info {
    guid: u32,
    ruid: u32,
    groups: Vec<u32>,
    num_groups: usize,
}

fn example(guid: u32) -> Info {
    unsafe {
        let ruid = libc::getuid();
        if -1 == libc::seteuid(guid) {
            panic!("seteuid")
        }

        let mut groups = Vec::new();
        let mut attempts = 0;
        loop {
            let num_groups = libc::getgroups(groups.capacity() as i32, groups.as_mut_ptr());
            if -1 == num_groups {
                panic!("getgroups")
            }

            let num_groups = num_groups as usize;

            if num_groups <= groups.capacity() {
                groups.set_len(num_groups);
                return Info {
                    guid,
                    ruid,
                    groups,
                    num_groups,
                };
            }

            groups.reserve_exact(num_groups);

            attempts += 1;
            if attempts >= 3 {
                panic!("Unstable amount of groups")
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", example(unsafe { libc::getuid() }));
}
```

However, I wouldn't rewrite all this and I'd rely on the existing work. The [nix crate](https://crates.io/crates/nix) provides nice wrappers:

```
extern crate nix;

use nix::unistd::{self, Uid};
use std::u32;

fn example(guid: Uid) -> nix::Result<()> {
    let ruid = unistd::getuid();
    let no_change = Uid::from_raw(u32::MAX);
    unistd::setresuid(no_change, guid, no_change)?;
    let groups = nix::unistd::getgroups()?;

    println!(
        "real user id {} as user id {}, as user groups {:?}",
        ruid, guid, groups
    );

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", example(Uid::current()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `nix` crate. Definitely better than using `libc` directly.