# How do I add the same integer to each element of a vector in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, addition

In Python, if I have a list and want to add 10 to each element I would do:

```py
bar = [2,4,5,6,7]
bar = [x + 10 for x in bar]
```

resulting in: `[12,14,15,16,17]`. How can this be done in Rust? Is the only way doing a for loop and going through each vector element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rust way to do this is very similar to Python: use iterators! The rough equivalent to Python's list comprehension is `iter::map` to get the new elements, and `iter::collect` to collect into a new vector (or some other kind of collection).

So for example, if `bar` is a `Vec<i32>` (or any other primitive integer type) and you want to add 10 to each element, try

```
bar = bar.into_iter().map(|x| x + 10).collect();
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7b75a4340d276dcca971f9a5b8b0d27)

Alternatively, you could mutate the elements in-place with

```
bar.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 10);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73b12592255bb96659c98b0c47f4279a)

This is basically like a for loop, but a bit more succinct. This is generally going to be more efficient than the first method since you don't need to allocate a new vector (a sufficiently smart compiler may be able to avoid this). The only downside is that this version is less flexible. The output still needs to be a vector; you couldn't switch to a hash set or what have you. You also wouldn't be able to keep a copy of the old vector. See below for some examples of what's possible.

```
fn main() {
    let mut bar = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    // Overwrite the old vector
    bar = bar.into_iter().map(|x| x + 10).collect();
    println!("new bar: {:?}", bar);

    let bar = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    // Make a completely new vector
    // Note that this works only because i32 implements the Copy trait,
    // so we can make copies of the elements of bar without any problems
    // In more general situations, we may need to clone each element
    let foo: Vec<_> = bar.iter().map(|&x| x + 10).collect();
    println!("old bar: {:?} (it's still around)", bar);
    println!("new foo: {:?}", foo);

    use std::collections::HashSet;
    let bar = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    // transform the data and collect it into a HashSet
    // instead of a vector
    let bar: HashSet<_> = bar.into_iter().map(|x| x + 10).collect();
    println!("new bar: {:?} (note that now bar is unordered)", bar);

    let mut bar = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    // Overwrite the old vector in place
    bar.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 10);
    println!("new bar: {:?}", bar);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8407ce7ab730184f654397311f8b365a)

Comment: Thank you, I just did not understand a part of the answer. When you say "The only downside is that this version is less flexible. The output still needs to be a vector; you couldn't switch to a hash set or what have you. " What do you mean by being less flexible and the output needs to be a vector? What would be the advantage of the hashSet method if the objective is to always work with a vector?

Comment: @Miguel Sometimes the objective isn't to always work with a vector. Or even when you're still working with vectors, if the type of the underlying data changes, you'll need a brand new vector. For example, if `strings` is a vector of type `Vec<String>`, then you wouldn't be able to do `strings.for_each().map(|s| *s = s.len())` since that would change the type of each string and the vector as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic code which illustrates how to do it the way the question assumes by default. It might be useful for beginners with Rust like me:

```
fn increment_mut(p: &mut Vec<i32>, to_add: i32){
    for i in 0..p.len() {
        p[i] += to_add;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    increment_mut(&mut p, 10);

    // Print the complete vector in Debug.
    println!("{:?}", p)
}
```

```
$ cargo run
[12, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

### Using `iter_mut`

```
fn increment_mut2(p: &mut Vec<i32>, to_add: i32) {
    for x in p.iter_mut() {
        *x += to_add;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = vec![2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    increment_mut2(&mut p, 10);

    // Print the complete vector in Debug.
    println!("{:?}", p)
}
```

```
$ cargo run
[12, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Comment: When possible, iterators are preferred. Direct index access can incur overhead due to checking for out-of-bounds access. `&mut Vec<_>` is non-idiomatic ([Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)). There are self-modifying operators (`+=`). `p.iter()` is usually written as `&`. It's not needed to dereference in the printing for loop ([Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and revision @Shepmaster, I will dig into this and try to improve this code.