# How can I improve the performance of my Rust code compared to Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, rust

How can I improve the performance of my Rust code as Python takes around 5 seconds to finish and Rust takes 7 seconds.

I am using `build --release`

**Rust code**

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;

    loop {
        n += 1;
        println!("The value of n is {}", &n);
        if n == 100000 {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Python3 code**

```py
n = 0
while True:
   n+=1
   print("The value of n is ",n)
   if n == 100000:
       break
```

Comment: Remove the print statement?

Comment: `build --release` is not a Rust command. Did you mean **`cargo build --release`**?

Comment: Tangentially, no need for `&n`: [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)

Comment: How do you compute the timings?

Comment: Without printing of any kind, I expect the Rust program to be completely optimized away to the equivalent of `fn main() {}`.

Answer (score 5):

If I recall correctly, `println` locks stdout. Taken from [Rust Performance Pitfalls](https://llogiq.github.io/2017/06/01/perf-pitfalls.html):

> [...] the default `print!` macros will lock STDOUT *for each write operation*. So if you have a larger textual output (or input from STDIN), you should lock manually.
>
> This:
>
> ```
> let mut out = File::new("test.out");
> println!("{}", header);
> for line in lines {
>     println!("{}", line);
>     writeln!(out, "{}", line);
> }
> println!("{}", footer);
> ```
>
> locks and unlocks io::stdout a lot, and does a linear number of (potentially small) writes both to stdout and the file. Speed it up with:
>
> ```
> {
>     let mut out = File::new("test.out");
>     let mut buf = BufWriter::new(out);
>     let mut lock = io::stdout().lock();
>     writeln!(lock, "{}", header);
>     for line in lines {
>         writeln!(lock, "{}", line);
>         writeln!(buf, "{}", line);
>     }
>     writeln!(lock, "{}", footer);
> }   // end scope to unlock stdout and flush/close buf>
> ```
>
> This locks only once and writes only once the buffer is filled (or buf is closed), so it should be much faster.
>
> Similarly, for network IO, you may want to use buffered IO.