# Why can I use a mutable variable such that its lifetime overlaps with an immutable reference, but I can't use a mutable reference in the same way?

Tags: variables, rust, reference, immutability, borrow-checker

I don't understand why the borrow checker **allows a mutable variable**'s lifetime to overlap with an immutable reference's lifetime, but **does not allow a mutable reference**'s lifetime to overlap with an immutable reference's lifetime.

this compiles:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("hello"); // some warning about s not needing to be mutable
let r = &s;
println!("{}, {}", r, s);
```

but this does not:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("hello");
let r_mut = &mut s; // mutable borrow here
let r = &s; // immutable borrow here
println!("{}, and {}", r, r_mut); // mutable borrow used here, error
```

Why can I use a **mutable variable in an immutable way** such that its lifetime overlaps with an immutable reference, but I can't use a **mutable reference in the same immutable way**?

Comment: I expect the reason is that println! (or whatever function it expands to) takes a non-mutable reference to `s` by default, whether or not the variable being borrowed is mutable.

Comment: @TimDestan, I understand how your comment explains why the first one compiles, but not why the second one does not

Comment: @attdona The code above still compiles when adding a function call mutating `s` either before the definition of `r` or after the `println`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first correct the terminology a bit.

Variable bindings don't have a lifetime. They have a *scope*. When a variable binding goes out of scope, the object it binds to will be dropped. This behaviour is not controlled by the borrow checker. Scopes are lexical, and easy to see when looking at the source code.

Borrows have lifetimes. These lifetimes will be inferred by the borrow checker, and they are not tied to the lexical structure of the code ("non-lexical lifetimes"), though they have been in the past. Lifetimes roughly extend from the point where the borrow is created to the point where it is last used.

When you create a borrow of a variable, the variable is marked as borrowed by the borrow checker. During the *lifetime* of the borrow, as inferred by the borrow checker, you can't mutate or move the borrowed variable, regardless of whether you declared the variable binding as mutable or not. If you created a shared borrow, you are allowed to create further shared borrows. Mutable borrows are exclusive, though – a variable that is mutably borrowed can't be used in any other way during the lifetime of the borrow.

These rules ensure that only one "handle" to a variable – either a binding or a mutable borrow – can be used to mutate a variable at any given time. This is the fundamental invariant Rust ensures. The fact that the scope of a mutable variable binding can overlap with the lifetime of a borrow does not change this, since you can't modify the variable via its binding during the lifetime of the borrow.

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a "mutable variable"; there are only *mutable variable bindings*. If you have ownership of an object, you can always bind mutably to it to modify it:

```
let s = "Hello".to_owned();
let mut s = s;
s.push_str(", world!");
```

There is one more subtlety to your code: `println!()` is a macro, not a function call. It expands to some code that only *borrows* the arguments you pass to `println!()`. So while it looks like you are passing ownership of `s` to `println!()`, you actually don't. If you use a macro taking ownership instead, the code stops compiling:

```
let mut s = String::from("hello");
let r = &s;
dbg!(r, s);
```

resulting in the error

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `s` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
3 |     let r = &s;
  |             -- borrow of `s` occurs here
4 |     dbg!(r, s);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     move out of `s` occurs here
  |     borrow later used here
  |
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

See also:

- [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)

Comment: so variables are fundamentally unlike references. The scope of a mutable variable can overlap with the lifetime of a mutable reference, so long as the variable is not 'used as a reference' itself during that lifetime.

Comment: This is a great explanation.  
@Captain_Obvious: I think it is more correct to say: The scope of a mutable variable can overlap with the lifetime
of a mutable reference, as long as the variable is "used as immutable" (read-only) during that lifetime.

Comment: @Captain_Obvious The lifetimes of mutable borrows can also overlap. You can create a mutable borrow `let b = &mut x` and then _reborrow_ it using `let c = &mut *b`. You can't use `b` for anything while it is reborrowed, but its lifetime definitely overlaps with the lifetime of `c`.

Comment: The invariant here is that there is only a single "handle" that can be used to modify the variable at any given time.