# When do I need to use a dereference in rust?

Tags: rust

In the following example we are using a reference to `self` in the `println!` and `show_type` functions yet we aren't dereferencing `self` with `*` to get the value.

Why aren't we using dereference in the example?

When do we need to use a dereference?

How can we print to screen if a variable is holding a reference or a value?

```
struct Animal<T> {
    name: T,
}
impl<T: Display> Animal<T> {
    fn show_type(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
        println!("{}", type_name::<T>()); 
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dog = Animal {
        name: String::from("Rex")
    }; 
    dog.show_type(); // Result: Rex, alloc::string::String
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why aren't we using dereference in the example?

Because it's not necessary.

> When do we need to use a dereference?

When the rust compiler does not auto-deref. Generally the rust compiler will auto-deref on attribute access and method calls (but only the "subject" of the call, parameters are not auto-deref'd). Though sometimes it's necessary to disambiguate.

> How can we print to screen if a valubale is holding a reference or a value?

[Because it's set up that way](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-85)

```rust
impl<'_, T> Display for &'_ T where
    T: Display + ?Sized
```

So there is an implementation of `Display` for any reference to something which implements `Display`, and it simply delegates through the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Field access expressions do automatic dereferncing in Rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html#automatic-dereferencing

And so I guess you would dereference manually when you need a whole value, not a specific field.

Comment: Note also that [`println!` implicitely takes its arguments by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30451360/5397009).