# cannot borrow `var` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

While trying to compile the following code, im getting an error:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `var` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

```rust
fn increment(num : &mut i32){
    *num = *num +1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut var : i32 = 123;
    let p_var: &mut i32   = &mut var;

    println!("{}", var);
    increment(p_var);
}
```

I have no clue what does it mean, can someone explain me exacly why am I getting this error?

Comment: Does it go away if you move the `println` before `let p_var ...` line?

Comment: This kind of error is explained in the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). You probably want to start there, because aliasing rules are covered pretty early on. Basically, you're trying to use Rust before you have learned it.

Comment: @Fildor Yes it does but what I wanted to achieve here was to invoke println!() and increment() alternately so that I can see variable changing its value

Comment: @cdhowie cool but where is it exacly in the Rust book?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html and following

Answer (score 2):

```
fn increment(num: &mut i32){
    *num = *num +1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut var : i32 = 123;
    
    println!("{}", var);
    increment(&mut var);
    println!("{}", var);
}
```

worked for me.

I, myself, am a Rust beginner, too. So, here is what my view on this is ( I *MAY* be utterly wrong ):

In this code `var` never gives up ownership and has no mutable borrows that are still in scope when it borrows immutably. I therefore can borrow it mutably to the increment function. After it has returned that borrow is not alive anymore. I therefore can borrow var` again to the println macro.

When you assigned to `p_var` you created a mutable borrow that was in scope and alive when you tried to borrow to the println macro, which is not allowed.

This is what the incredible cargo told me:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `var` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:9:20
   |
7  |     let p_var : &mut i32 = &mut var;
   |                            -------- mutable borrow occurs here
8  |
9  |     println!("{}", var);
   |                    ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
10 |     increment(p_var);
   |               ----- mutable borrow later used here
   |
```

It would be great if some more experienced rustacian could verify (or correct) my reasoning and assessment.

Comment: It does work, thank you, but I still dont understand why cant I use seperate reference and invoke funcitons like you

Comment: @BIGoperaFAN one of the ownership/borrowing rules is *"mutable references are exclusive"* which means no one else can modify or even read the value while there's a mutable reference still alive.

Comment: @Fildor *"still alive"* does NOT mean *"still in scope"* thanks to [non-lexical-lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes). The borrow checker will consider the reference "alive" only until its last usage.

Comment: @kmdreko Thx for the clarification. Still learning. So my explanation in the answer is wrong? Or at least not accurate?

Comment: ^^ I edited to take kmdreko's information into account.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible due to Rust mutable reference rules.

> Until there is a mutable reference is alive in a lifetime scope, the only way to access that referent is the that alive reference.

In your case you already have `p_var` alive, so the only way to access it is through `p_var`. Hence you are violating the rust mutable reference rules.

For example this works:

```
fn increment(num : &mut i32){
    *num = *num +1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut var : i32 = 123;
    
    
    {
        let p_var: &mut i32   = &mut var;
        increment(p_var);
    }
        

    println!("{}", var);
}
```

This works because `println!("{}", var)` ran, `p_var` life time has already ended. If you try to reference `var` inside the {} scope it won't work either.

Comment: I dont quite understand how invoking ``println!`` with ``var`` is counted as borrowing

Comment: @BIGoperaFAN `println!` needs to be able to read `var` to print it. It could take ownership of `var` (ie. you could move `var` into `println!`), but then you wouldn't be able to use it after printing it. This is probably never what you want, so `println!` always borrows its arguments.

Comment: @tobiasvl Thanks, your comment explaines everything. I was thinking it could not borrow because Im passing ``var`` and not  ``&var`` to it, but now im reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable.