# Why formatting value vs ref generates different assembly in Rust?

Tags: rust

My (limited) understanding is that `format!("{}", v)` and `format!("{}", &v)` are essentially identical, and should generate identical assembly code and identical performance results. This is based on reading [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable/30451360#30451360)).  Yet, when comparing these two functions, [the assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/3hKz55qsh) is somewhat different. Is this expected, or is this a missing Rust compiler optimization?  Or is there some edge case in which it is important to generate different code?

```rust
pub fn bar(j: i32) -> String {
    format!("bar {}", j)
}

// vs

pub fn foo(i: i32) -> String {
    format!("foo {}", &i)
}
```

#### Benchmarks

Running [benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/nyurik/16495ecf3034052803ceb1b26b8ac8a9) produces ~6% difference in performance:

[image: Performance comparison graph]

#### See also

- [suggested Clippy lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/10851)
- [Rust compiler bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/112156)

Comment: I think it's because `<&i32 as core::fmt::Display>::fmt` doesn't get inlined. If it did, then I would expect the assembly to be identical. You can see this function gets emitted in the `&i` case, and then -- obviously -- `foo` has to actually give it the address of the `i32` instead of the `i32` itself.

Comment: @cdhowie is this declared somewhere in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/core/src/fmt/num.rs ?  Also, do you think this is a bug of a missing `#[inline]` ?

Comment: Not only; the formatting machinery is hard for LLVM to optimize as it's using dynamic dispatch.